# How to find people in a database who live in the same cities?

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, and I'm asking for help in an apparently easy question, but it gets cumbersome in my mind.

I have the following table:

```
ID   NAME   CITY
---------------------
1    John   new york
2    Sam    new york
3    Tom    boston
4    Bob    boston
5    Jan    chicago
6    Ted    san francisco
7    Kat    boston
```

I want a query that returns all the people who live in a city that another person registered in the database also lives in.

The answer, for the table I showed above, would be:

```
ID   NAME   CITY
---------------------
1    John   new york
2    Sam    new york
3    Tom    boston
4    Bob    boston
7    Kat    boston
```

Comment: The answer does not depend on which SQL engine is being used, it can easily be answered in engine-neutral SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a two part question:

1. What cities have more than one user located in them?
2. What users live in that subset of cities?

Let's answer it in two parts.  Let's also make the simplifying assumption (not stated in your question) that the Users table has only one entry per user per city.

To find cities with more than one user:

```
 SELECT City FROM Users GROUP BY City HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now, let's find all the users for those cities:

```
SELECT ID, User, City FROM Users 
   WHERE City IN (SELECT City FROM Users GROUP BY CITY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.city = t.city AND t1.name <> t.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the rows that have the same city more than 1 time:

```
SELECT persons.*
FROM persons
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons AS p GROUP BY CITY HAVING p.CITY = persons.CITY) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a correlated subquery which leads to a nested loop, you could perform a self join:

```
SELECT id, name, city
FROM persons
   JOIN (SELECT city
         FROM persons
         GROUP BY city HAVING count(*) > 1) AS cities
      USING (city);
```

This might be the most performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
This can be expressed many ways.  Here is one possible way:

select * from persons p
where exists (
    select 1 from persons p2
    where p2.city = p.city and p2.name <> p.name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a different flavor from the others that have posted.

```
 SELECT     ID,
            name,
            city
 FROM       (SELECT     DISTINCT
                        ID,
                        name,
                        city,
                        COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS cityCount
             FROM       table) t
 WHERE      cityCount > 1
```